# Inserting data from VB.NET to MS Access: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, syntax-error

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and im trying to make a registration form for my account database using VB.NET. This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub btnRegistery_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegistery.Click
    Dim usernme, passwrd As String
    usernme = txtUsernm.Text
    passwrd = txtpasswrd.Text

    Dim myconnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim constring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\hasan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\hasan\Login_Info.accdb"
    myconnection = New OleDbConnection(constring)
    myconnection.Open()

    Dim sqlQry As String

    sqlQry = "INSERT INTO tbl_user(username, password) VALUES(usernme , passwrd)"

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, myconnection)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub
```

The code compiles fine, but when i try to register any new information i get the following message:

```
    A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' 
    occurred in System.Data.dll
    Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.    
    If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

What could be a solution and cause for this problem?

Comment: I would also suggest that you move any database code out of the User Interface code behind and into a separate DLL to ensure better separation of concerns.

Comment: I would also recommend that you don't hard code connection strings but store them in the app.config file so you can "adjust" the location of the MSAccess db without re-compiling.

Answer (score 7):

Your query seems wrong: `... VALUES(usernme, passwrd)...` -- 
Here the `usernme`and `passwrd` are not variables for database, but just plain text in the query.

Use parameters, like this:

```
Dim usernme, passwrd As String
usernme = txtUsernm.Text
passwrd = txtpasswrd.Text
Dim constring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\hasan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\hasan\Login_Info.accdb"
Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection(constring)
    myconnection.Open()
    Dim sqlQry As String = "INSERT INTO [tbl_user] ([username], [password]) VALUES (@usernme, @passwrd)"
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, myconnection)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usernme", usernme)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passwrd", passwrd)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End using
End using
```

Comment: i dont understand.. what should i do with sqlQry and where does it fit in in the code above?

Comment: Check my answer I update it with new query

Comment: but myconnection is now undeclared.. leaving the original bit of code that declared it still gives me the same error

Comment: Error happened in database, on my opinion query looks fine(new query).Then check that table, field names are right. Then check if length declared in database for fields `username` and `password` are more or same then inputed values

Comment: Can you run this query straight to your database(with Access)? Then you can get maybe more information about error

Comment: i dont understand what you mean.. how do i do that?

Comment: Just open your database file(Login_Info.accdb) with Access, and run SQL Command...

Comment: im really sorry, but as ive said im pretty new to this.. can you explain further

Comment: im gonna go sleep now.. its 2 am where im at, ill take a look at it tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

You aren't including the actual variable information missing the quotations, like

```
VALUES ('" & usernme & '", ...etc
```

You should be using parameters to avoid errors and sql injection:

```
sqlQry = "INSERT INTO tbl_user (username, password) VALUES(@usernme, @passwrd)"

Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, myconnection)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usernme", usernme)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passwrd", passwrd)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: I think error is not because of missing quotations...

Comment: @Fabio Sure it is.  I just didn't write it out because the better instruction is to use parameters.

Comment: Without parameters he will need: add quotations and `&`-sign to concat SQL query and values of variables

Comment: @Fabio That's what I was implying.  I updated the post.

Comment: i tried this and it gave me the same error..

Comment: @user3140727 Make sure your table and field names are correct.

Comment: i did, nothing wrong there

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

Private Sub RefreshData()
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        '-------------open connection-----------
        cnn.Open()
    End If

    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select stdID as [StdIdTxt]," &
                                       "Fname as [FnameTxt] ,Lname,BDy,age,gender,address,email,LNO,MNO,course" &
                                       "from studentTB order by stdID", cnn)

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    '------------fill data to data table------------
    da.Fill(dt)



    'close connection
    cnn.Close()


End Sub



Private Sub AddNewBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddNewBtn.Click
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    '--------------open connection if not yet open---------------
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnn.Open()
    End If
    cmd.Connection = cnn

    '----------------add data to student table------------------
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into studentTB (stdID,Fname,Lname,BDy,age,gender,address,email,LNO,MNO,course)" &
        "values (" & Me.StdIdTxt.Text & "','" & Me.FnameTxt.Text & "','" & Me.LNameTxt.Text & "','" &
        Me.BdyTxt.Text & "','" & Me.AgeTxt.Text & "','" & Me.GenderTxt.Text & "','" &
        Me.AddTxt.Text & "','" & Me.EmailTxt.Text & "','" & Me.Hometxt.Text & "','" & Me.mobileTxt.Text & "','" & Me.Coursetxt.Text & "')"


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    '---------refresh data in list----------------
    'RefreshData()

    '-------------close connection---------------------
    cnn.Close()
```

Comment: More prone to SQL injections and somehow error when a string text contains single quote.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for submitting an answer, but there are a couple of problems with it: **(1)** It is a "code dump" answer with absolutely no explanation as to how it solves the OP's problem(s). Even a brief introductory sentence like "This code uses [some technique] to avoid the error." would have helped. **(2)** Your code concatenates user input directly into the SQL statement, leaving it vulnerable to *SQL Injection*. That is **bad practice**. You should have used a [parameter query](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6bdf8b71-1cf1-41c0-848c-4fca2c9e1ea2).

Answer (score -1):

This insert error is nothing but a syntax error, there is no need for changing your code. please avoid reserved words like "password" form your database. This error is due to the field name password

Answer (score -3):

The SQL string should look like this

```
sqlQry = "INSERT INTO tbl_user(username, password) VALUES(" & usernme  & "', " & passwrd & ")"
```

The values usernme & passwrd aren't valid to the database.
Beyond that you really should look into using a Command object and parameters.

Comment: The irony that your answer is missing some quotes.

Comment: And vulnerable for SQL Injection...